# How to simulate saturations and thresholds with Scipy?

Tags: python, scipy

how to simulate saturations and thresholds with scipy?

I precise my question
I want to simulate with scipy a system like the one described by the block diagram below.
If the system had only linear transfer functions, there would be no problem, but here I have a non-linear block, a saturation (it could there be a threshold)
What is the solution to program and simulate the block diagram.
[image]

with:

```
PT2=1/(1+s+s^2) and 
P=K=100
```

Comment: Ehm, what? 'you have another method to simulate'??? Can you please at least simulate having done some research on this topic? BTW, this question really isn't clear (I don't understand neither what you're asking about, nor what your goal is), could you add more details, please?

Comment: I hope I have sufficiently clarify the issue

Comment: Does your block diagram represent a model in some other simulation environment? Can you describe what each block does? Do you have names for the output nodes? Have you looked at SciySim (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ScipySim)?

Comment: yes I use SimApp [link](http://www.simapp.com/) you can also use Scilab  or matlab to run this example.

I don't know ScipySim, haye you some example with this package.

Sorry for my English, I am french

Comment: Don't worry about your English, it's better than my French, and anyway people shouldn't criticize it on Stack Overflow. But adding 'scipy' to the question may have thrown people off -- you could have instead asked for help finding packages that do block diagrams, or that are Python equivalents for simulink or something (actually Googling for that would have found BMS)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [Steven Masfaraud's block module simulator (BMS)](http://pythonhosted.org/bms/getting_started.html). As of August 2016 it has nonlinear block elements for Saturation, Coulomb, Dead Zone, and Hysteresis. Here's [a link to one of his examples](https://github.com/masfaraud/BMSpy/blob/master/examples/second_order.py).

The other option on [this Quora post](https://www.quora.com/When-will-there-be-a-Simulink-like-alternative-for-Python) is [PyLinX](https://github.com/PyLinX-Project/PyLinX).

It looks like SciPySim may no longer be under development, from [this link](https://code.google.com/archive/p/scipy-sim/) that states *"Please note that this project is no longer being actively developed or maintained."*.